# Why is this Firebase Database rule being evaluated as true if it's not supposed to?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm testing the security of my data on Firebase. I've been on the documentation quite some time lately and I thought I understood it, but when doing something like this on the simulator I'm left with my head scratching:

[image: Firebase WTF]

The rule states:

```
"propiedades": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
    ".validate": "data.child('owner').val() === auth.token.sub"
}
```

and neither is `data.child('owner').val()` in this particular case being `"s0kf6RvEzmfGGjVq9q14GQ6s14H32"` not equal to `"s0kf6RvEzmfGGjVq9q14GQ6s14H3"` (there is a trailing "2") nor `auth.token` is supposed to be `=== data.child('owner').val()` but specifically `auth.token.sub` is supposed to. What the heck is going on here?

As a side note, the operation goes through even though the strings are equal and even when I change the rule to something like this:

```
"propiedades": { 
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "$id" : {
      ".validate": "data.child('owner').val() === auth.token.sub"
    }
}
```

The heavy editing comes from the fact that I'm testing with all possible combinations and everything is going against my logic. I'm very confused at this point.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're checking whether `"propriedades/owner" === auth.token.sub` but when you're writing data you're writing to a child `"fgdfg"` of `"propriedades"` which means your owner node will end up in `"propriedades/fgdfg/owner"`.

You were on the right track with

```
"propiedades": { 
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "$id" : {
        ".validate": "data.child('owner').val() === auth.token.sub"
    }
}
```

except you should be using `newData` instead of `data`. `data` refers to the Data as it exists in the db currently, since there's no data at that location yet (assumably) it always returns true. `newData` will verify the data as it was, and the new data, so that's what you should be using. Also, for me, auth.token.sub never seems to work so I use auth.uid instead, if auth.token.sub works for you, you can keep it in. But I would replace it with auth.uid.

These are the correct rules:

```
"propiedades": { 
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "auth != null",
    "$id" : {
        ".validate": "newData.child('owner').val() === auth.uid"
    }
}
```

Comment: The validation also passed when I took the "fgdfg" children out as well. I also tested with `data` and `newData` in several places. Anyway, this did the trick, thanks